# Mysql error code creating table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
create table Order (ord_no int, purch_amt int check(purch_amt < 50), customer_id varchar(30), salesman_id varchar(30), Primary Key (ord_no));
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (ord_no int, purch_amt int check(purch_amt < 50), customer_id varchar(30),' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in MySQL.  Use some other name.

See this related post: [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

I think you can use back-ticks to quote your table name, but I think that is not a great idea.

Comment: thanks... it worked